# Export MFC CView into vectorial format

Tags: pdf, view, printing, mfc, svg

With my MFC application, I am able to print my CDocument on screen using the CView class.
Basically, I use the CDC class to write text and draw polygons on screen to provide a view representation of my document.

Now let's say I would like to use that output view in Microsoft Word.

From a user point a view and without anymore developer work, I can :

- copy-paste my drawing to word : this produces a raster BMP file which I am able to paste in Word
- print my drawing and use a PDF exporter : this produces a vectorial PDF file which is light and zoom-able, but not easy to reuse in Word.

These two effortless solutions are great because I can keep the exact layout of my view, but have cons (raster or format)

Another way to solve my problem would be to write SVG or VML but I would not get the same layout and this would require a lot of work.

Is there a library to do the same kind of PDF export / print mechanism into a standard format ?

What would you suggest ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried drawing to an enhanced metafile (EMF)?

Comment: No but how would I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw your view into a Enhanced Meta File, first read the documentation @ MSDN: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/427wezx1%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Here is an example, how this works:

```
CMetaFileDC MFDC;

CRect rect(0,0,width,height);

MFDC.CreateEnhanced(NULL,NULL,rect,NULL);
MFDC.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
MFDC.SetMapMode(MM_HIMETRIC);

CDC tempDC;
tempDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&MFDC);
MFDC.SetAttribDC(tempDC.m_hDC);

// now you draw into the DC like it was your original view

HENHMETAFILE hEnhMetaFile = MFDC.CloseEnhanced();
HENHMETAFILE hEMF = NULL;
hEMF = CopyEnhMetaFile(hEnhMetaFile,"C:\\Temp\\Test.emf");
DeleteEnhMetaFile(hEMF);
DeleteEnhMetaFile(hEnhMetaFile);
```

Comment: Thank you dwo. I think the lines with `CreateCompatibleDC` `SetAttribDC` are not useful, aren't they ?

Comment: If you use methods like `GetTextExtent` or the like, you need to set the attrib DC. Otherwise leave it null.

Comment: I'm trying to import the generated WMF file in AutoCAD, but it fails. On the other side, importing standard ones like WordArt which come with Office works. So I guess I am not producing a clean meta file. I also tried to use the not enhanced versions of the MFC library, but it didn't change anything. Any clue ?

Comment: Did you call `CreateEnhanced` and `CopyEnhMetaFile` or just `CopyMetaFile`?

Comment: I used the methods with/without `Enhanced` and `Enh`keywords. The problem is that it was generating EMF not exactly WMF. So I used the piece of code solve the problem, nevermind. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3962/Using-GDI-with-MFC-or-native-C-C

Comment: The text doesn't print well (using Arial font) on Windows 7/64 bit machine. It prints well on screen (on the CView) but not on the file (EMF or WMF) whereas on Windows XP/32 bit everything was fine.

Comment: This is strange. I have such code running under both systems and can't tell any difference. I think you should create a new question with a good code sample and description!

Comment: I think it may be related to the LOGFONT structure. My code is basically preparing a LOGFONT structure to create a `CFont` using the `CreateFontIndirect(const LOGFONT* lplf)` method. Choosing the charset and family of the font seems tricky and might not work the same on two systems.

Comment: It seems that building the program under the Windows 7 environment solves the problem. What I did is build on WinXP/32 and ran on Win7/64. I used the same code and the same version of the compiler Visual Studio 2008.